# Options for a Multibranch Pipeline on an Azure Devops repository?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When you configure a multibranch pipeline, you have to give it at least one a source for under "Branch Sources".

When using a GitHub or a BitBucket repository, you are able to add them as GitHub or BitBucket repositories, and not generic git repositories.  This allows Jenkins to be informed immediately when new commits or branches are added.

Without that (if it's added as a generic git repository), Jenkins has to continually poll the repository to find out if there are any new commits or branches.

Is there any way to add Azure Devops repositories as Devops Repositories instead of as generic git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create generic multibranch jobs, and then configure into your devops azure project settings a service hook jenkins with the actions:

- Event pushed -> Trigger Git Build
- Event Pull request merge attempt -> Trigger Git Build

In each of those you need to configure the user and token to you jenkins server.

With this you can disable pooling as devops azure will trigger events to you jenkins.

Comment: Will this trigger a pull request? When adding a generic git multibranch pull requests are not shown on jenkins as no specific job is created for the pull request.

Also, one thing is to trigger the build, the other, is to show the result of the execution also on Devops azure appart from jenkins.